# How do I retrieve one specific piece of data from a XML file using XMLreader?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, processing

A real example of the XML data I have to parse through and how the file is configured. this is how the file is presented to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <session>
  <values>
   <value id="FILE_CREATE_DATE">
    <timestamp>2012-04-16T21:33:31Z</timestamp>
   </value>
   <value id="LAST_ACCESSED">
    <timestamp>2012-09-17T17:15:23Z</timestamp>
   </value>
   <value id="VERSION_TIMESTAMP">
    <timestamp>2012-04-16T21:33:31Z</timestamp>
   </value>
 </values>
</session>
```

I need to go into this file and retrieve the FILE_CREATE_DATE data.

My code so far:

```js
    File xmlFile = new File(XMLFileData[i].getPath());
    FileInputStream myXMLStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);

    XMLInputFactory XMLFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader XMLReader =  XMLFactory.createXMLStreamReader(myXMLStream);
    while(XMLReader.hasNext())
    {
       if (XMLReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT)
       {        
          String XMLTag = XMLReader.getLocalName();
          if(XMLReader.hasText())
          {
             System.out.println(XMLReader.getText());
             break;
          }                            
       }    
       XMLReader.next();
    }
```

the 'getLocalName()' function returns 'Sessions' then 'value' then 'values' but never returns the actual name of the element. I need to test to see if  I am at the right element then retrieve the data from that element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
XMLInputFactory XMLFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader XMLReader = XMLFactory.createXMLStreamReader(myXMLStream);
            while(XMLReader.hasNext())
            {
                if (XMLReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT)
                {        
                   String XMLTag = XMLReader.getLocalName();
                   if(XMLTag.equals("value"))
                   {
                      String idValue = XMLReader.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
                      if (idValue.equals("FILE_CREATE_DATE"))
                      {
                        System.out.println(idValue);
                        XMLReader.nextTag();
                        System.out.println(XMLReader.getElementText());

                      }
                   }
               }    
               XMLReader.next();
            }
```

So this code is the final result of all my anguish on the topic of recovering specific data from a XML data file.  I want to thank everyone who helped me out with answers - regardless on if it was what I was looking for they got me thinking and that led to the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Your id is not an element - it's element attribute.

You should read attribute of your value node, see the javadoc for getAttributeValue method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getAttributeValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

> Returns the normalized attribute value of the attribute with the
>   namespace and localName If the namespaceURI is null the namespace is
>   not checked for equality

So it will be:

```
String XMLTag = XMLReader.getLocalName();
if(XMLTag.equals("value")) {
   String idValue = XMLReader.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
   //here idValue will be equal to FILE_CREATE_DATE, LAST_ACCESSED or VERSION_TIMESTAMP
}
```

Comment: thank you! this got me on the right track...I needed to recover the data at this spot in the XML file and I was having on heck of a time until this.

Answer (score 0):

I use Jsoup which is a library for parsing HTML. But it can be used for xml too. you would first have to load the XML file into a Document object then simply call

```
doc.getElementById("FILE_CREATE_DATE");
```

This will return an Element object that will have the timestamp as a child. Here's a link to the library: https://jsoup.org/

This is my first StackOverflow answer so let me know if it helps !

Comment: I spent all of last week working (or trying to work with) the document data type but all I ever got returned to it was a null value... I have gotten a lot further using XML reader. I just could not get this to return anything other than  a null value when I called the getDocument function. Thank you for your response though, all responses help me think...

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
if(XMLReader.getAttributeValue(0).equalIgnorecase("FILE_CREATE_DATE"))
```

[getAttributeValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getAttributeValue(int)) : Return value of the given index of the attribute. for

```
<value id="FILE_CREATE_DATE">
```

id is the first attribute. So XMLReader.getAttributeValue(0)

but before calling this you have to validate whether element has the first attribute. Because all the tags does not have at least 1 attribute.

in jsoup you can query like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Document doc;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dropbox.com/public/xml/yourfile.xml").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    //<value id="FILE_CREATE_DATE">
    Elements links = doc.select("value[id=FILE_CREATE_DATE]");
    for (Element link : links) {            
        if(link.attr("id").contains("FILE_CREATE_DATE"))//find the link with some texts
        {
            System.out.println("here is the element you need");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```